# Create a div using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/69934/

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: ''
  },
  methods:{
  randomize: function(){
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < message; i++){  
    arr[i] = i;
     }
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = arr;
  }
  }
})
```

There is a code suuposed to create and to print an array from 1 to n into HTML.

Anyway it never happens as it is said variable message is not defined.

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: You should use this.message instead of message. Also, you're missing the whole point of vuejs if you're manipulating the dom by hand. Your randomize method should just mute data who will then be rendered by a template

Comment: @Axnyff can you provide a more deep description of what You are speaking about? I'm all new to Vue and JS, wanna see a good approach from the very start!

Comment: What do you want to do with your randomize method, replace the already displayed list?

Comment: @Axnyff I'm gonna now, as I have an array add a button and after show different arrays, that will be randomized by standard methods, which I'll write evidently (instead of using Math.random() )

Comment: I'm not sure I understood everything, anyway, I made a little example: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/69996/. In this example, I never touch the DOM, I simply mutate the data of my vue model (with this.arr = arr) and the DOM is automatically updated

Comment: @Axnyff very useful! Many thanks!

Comment: If you want to get started with Vue, the documentation is really awesome: the get started section is especially really good to get the spirit of the framework: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: @Axnyff second day of my reading it :)

Comment: Awesome, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.message` to get something from `data`.

Complete code:

```
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
    message: ''
 },
 methods:{
    randomize: function(){
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.message; i++){  
           arr[i] = i;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = arr;
     }
   }
})
```